# Error with type bounds in function definition

Tags: scala

I have some class hierarchy:

```
trait Params
trait ParamsWithName extends Params {
  val name: String
}
case class ParamsWithNameAndValue(name: String, value: String) extends ParamsWithName
```

I want to implement a few classes that will use these. The following works:

```
trait Worker[T <: ParamsWithName] {
  def work(parameters: T): String = parameters.name
}

class SimpleWorker extends Worker[ParamsWithNameAndValue] {
  override def work(parameters: ParamsWithNameAndValue): String = s"${parameters.name} + ${parameters.value}"
}
```

The following does not:

```
trait Worker {
  def work[T <: ParamsWithName](parameters: T): String = parameters.name
}

class SimpleWorker extends Worker {
  override def work[ParamsWithNameAndValue](parameters: ParamsWithNameAndValue): String = s"${parameters.name} + ${parameters.value}"
}
```

The error is:

```
error: value name is not a member of type parameter ParamsWithNameAndValue
  override def work[ParamsWithNameAndValue](parameters: ParamsWithNameAndValue): String = s"${parameters.name} + ${parameters.value}"
error: value value is not a member of type parameter ParamsWithNameAndValue
  override def work[ParamsWithNameAndValue](parameters: ParamsWithNameAndValue): String = s"${parameters.name} + ${parameters.value}"
```

I would like to understand why this is the case.

Scala version is 2.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```scala
trait Worker[T <: ParamsWithName] {
  def work(parameters: T): String = parameters.name
}
```

Means that the `Worker` type itself is parametric on `T` *(which must be a subtype of `ParamsWithName`)*. Which implies that a concrete instance of `Worker` will only  work for one such concrete type for `T`

Thus, here:

```scala
class SimpleWorker extends Worker[ParamsWithNameAndValue] {
```

You are saying that the `SimpleWorker` type is a subtype of `Worker[ParamsWithNameAndValue]` meaning that all instances of `SimpleWorker` are instances of `Worker[ParamsWithNameAndValue]`

---

Whereas, this:

```scala
trait Worker {
  def work[T <: ParamsWithName](parameters: T): String = parameters.name
}
```

Means that any instance of `Worker` has a method `work` which is parametric on `T` *(which must be a subtype of ParamsWithName)*. Implying that any `Worker` must be able to handle any possible type `T`

Thus, here:

```scala
class SimpleWorker extends Worker {
  override def work[ParamsWithNameAndValue](parameters: ParamsWithNameAndValue): String = s"${parameters.name} + ${parameters.value}"
}
```

You are not only having a syntax error, but a conceptual problem. 
Because you want to say that the `work` method on `SimpleWorker` can only accept `ParamsWithNameAndValue` but that would be a violation of the **Liskov** substitution principle.

---

In conclusion, the first approach is the one that encodes the intention you want.

Comment: So `def work[T <: ParamsWithName]` in the trait means you cannot just implement the method for a concrete type that is a subtype of ParamsWithName? Even in `SimpleWorker` implementation it should still be able to handle all `T <: ParamsWithName`?

Comment: @toni057 yes, because `def work[T]` means that work is generic, it has to handle all possible values of `T` - Whereas if the class is the generic, then you can create a concrete instance of the class that handles only the type you want.